# Attempt to execute script as a function

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot this in MATLAB:

```
x=[-2:0.01:4];
y=3.5.^(-0.5*x).*cos(6*x);
plot(x,y)
```

but it gives an error like this:

> Attempt to execute SCRIPT plot as a function:
>   C:\Users\User\Downloads\Private\New folder (2)\Desktop\plot.m
>
> Error in plot67 (line 3)
>   plot(x,y)

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 10):

Rename your script "plot.m" to something else. There's a name conflict. It thinks you're calling your own script and not the plot-function.

Comment: It really should work. Check your folder. It sees a script that has the name *plot* (hence your error message).

Comment: you can run the command `which plot` to see which `plot` file is found on the MATLAB path. There should be only one entry, and it should say 'built-in [filepath]'. If there are multiple entries or the only listed entry is not a built-in function, try removing the path(s) that don't point to the built-in function

Comment: `which plot` only gives one entry. You shold try `which plot - all` and check if the entry that starts with `built-in` is labelled as `Shadowed`

Answer (score 3):

Please check in the current folder of MATLAB that you might have already created a file in the name plot.m

please delete or rename the file and try to plot.

then try to plot.

Comment: Right. It happened for nonMATLAB function (my case 'dolarIn' ) function was created at down level folder, after removing its OK.   In such cases, right click help option shows empty window. This might be bug in 2017 version.